# How to do record all programs activity on a PC and CPU/network/traffic usage on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, monitoring, performance-monitor

I would like to analyze all activities on my Win7 PC, of any programs.
I speak about CPU and memory usage, Network/Internet traffic consumption, but on daily basis.

How can i record that activities log with all the data?

Answer (score 3):

A good starting tool should by the ProcessMonitor from Microsoft Sysinternals.

You can download it from here: http://download.sysinternals.com/files/ProcessMonitor.zip

Comment: The sysinternals tools are well worth the time to learn to use. Many issues I couldn't figure out were solved quickly once you find and use the right tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to record the data the tools are built into Windows natively, this is called the [Windows performance monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744567(v=ws.10).aspx).

This allows to record all data and/or create events that will trigger recording.